# Running u-boot hello_world on an image partition with qemu

Tags: image, qemu, u-boot

I'm developing on an ubuntu x86 machine, trying to run the u-boot hello_world standalone application which resides on an image `sd.img` which contains a partition.

I've compiled u-boot (`v2022.10`) with `qemu-x86_64_defconfig`

I run qemu with `qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -nographic -bios u-boot.rom -drive format=raw,file=sd.img`

u-boot starts up, doesn't find a script, doesn't detect tftp, and awaits a command. If I type `ext4ls ide 0:1`, I can clearly see hello_world.bin (`3932704 hello_world.bin`).

When I do a `ext4load ide 0:1 0x40000 hello_world.bin` (in preparation for `go 40000 This is another test`), qemu/u-boot restarts.

0x40000 is the `CONFIG_STANDALONE_LOAD_ADDR` for x86.

I have even tried making an image of hello_world `mkimage -n "Hello stand alone" -A x86_64 -O u-boot -T standalone -C none -a 0x40000 -d hello_world.bin -v hello_world.img` and tried to load the image into 0x40000 with the intention of using `bootm` in case of cache issues - qemu/u-boot still resets.

Could anyone possibly point out the basic mistake I'm making.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory area 0xa0000-0xffffff is reserved and you are overwriting it when loading your 4 MiB file to 040000 due to the excessive size of the file.

If you build hello_world.bin correctly, it will be a few kilobytes.